# rxJs publishLast not flushing out messages

Tags: rxjs, observable

I've just read http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html and I was trying to get the publishLast working with some basic observables and I couldn't, can someone explain why?

```
        let obs = Observable.create((observer: Observer<number>): void => {
      observer.next(234);
    })
        .publishLast()
        .refCount();

    obs.subscribe((v: number) => console.log("1st subscriber: " + v));
    setTimeout(() => {
      obs.subscribe((v: number) => console.log("2nd subscriber: " + v));
    }, 1100);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that by "flushing out" you mean that you are not receiving any events in your subscribe block.

The problem is that `publishLast` can only emit when it knows the `Observable` will not be emitting any more values, and the only way it can do that is if you call `complete` on the `Observer`.

So your code needs to look like this:

```
let obs = Observable.create((observer: Observer<number>): void => {
  observer.next(234);
  observer.complete();
})
.publishLast()
.refCount();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My use case is this, I have a behaviorSubject that maps into an http call, and I would like it to return the last result to everyone, but if the behaviorSubject changes it should make a new http call, and notify it's subscribers. Is there any way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

@user2555964 For your use case, combining switchMap with distinctUntilChanged might provide a solution. Take a look an Angular's documentation where they use these two operators to implement a real-time search box
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#herosearchcomponent